# Error when using usercentrics (via gtm) and id's in some components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, cookieconsent

we try to switch from our own implemented CMP to usercentrics. Therefore we integrated usercentrics via gtm on our page. I realized that the element is only shown on our subpages and is not visible on our root page.
After two days of removing and adding components again. I found out that usercentrics was able to load when I removed the `id={"process"}` from the component. I'm using multiple times the `id` tag for a smoothscroll plugin on our page. But only the one applied on the process and the one applied on the contact section are the ones that lead to the error below.

After I removed the plugin and nearly all id's beside one, I got the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'REACT_APP_SC_ATTR' of undefined
    at bundle_legacy.js:1
    at bundle_legacy.js:15
```

We're using a Gatsby Stack with Typescript and `gatsby-plugin-smoothscroll` for scrolling.

We implemented gtm via a Gatsby Plugin as well: `gatsby-plugin-google-tagmanager`

```
import React from "react";
import colors from "../../../../config/GlobalStyles";
import {Container, Grid, makeStyles, Typography} from "@material-ui/core";

// @ts-ignore
import infoGraphic from "../../../../images/root/process/infographic.webp";
import {graphql, useStaticQuery} from "gatsby";
import Markdown from "markdown-to-jsx";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    contentWrapper: {
        paddingTop: "50px"
    },
    container: {
        paddingTop: "50px",
        backgroundColor: "white",
    },
    headline: {
        fontWeight: 600,
        color: colors.main
    },
    secondHeadline: {
        fontFamily: "Mackay",
        color: colors.main,
        fontWeight: 400,
    },
    infoGraphicWrapper: {
        overflow: "scroll",
        [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
            marginTop: "50px",
        },
        "& img": {
            [theme.breakpoints.down('sm')]: {
                maxWidth: "200%"
            }
        }
    }
}));

export default function ProcessSection() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const data = useStaticQuery(query);

    return (
        <section>
            <Container className={classes.container}>
                <Typography variant={"h2"} component={"h2"} className={classes.headline}>
                    <Markdown>
                        {data.strapiHome.process.headline}
                    </Markdown>
                </Typography>
                <Typography variant={"h2"} component={"h2"} className={classes.secondHeadline}>
                    <Markdown>
                        {data.strapiHome.process.secondHeadline}
                    </Markdown>
                </Typography>
                <Grid container className={classes.contentWrapper} justify={"space-between"}>
                    <Grid item xl={4} lg={4} md={4} sm={12} xs={12}>
                        <Typography component={"div"} variant={"body2"}>
                            <Markdown>{data.strapiHome.process.text}</Markdown>
                        </Typography>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid item xl={7} lg={7} md={7} sm={12} xs={12} className={classes.infoGraphicWrapper}>
                        <img src={infoGraphic} alt={"alt text"} />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Container>
        </section>
    );
}

const query = graphql`
    query {
        strapiHome {
            process {
                headline
                secondHeadline
                text
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

I have no idea where this is coming from and what the env variables mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by removing all id's from my components and add some of them again.

I was not able to understand why this happened.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is not in the code. To my point of view, it is related to the `.env` file.

If you are using `process.env.REACT_APP_SC_ATTR` somewhere, check the .env file to see if `REACT_APP_SC_ATTR` is defined.

`.env` file is like a global config. We normally add server url, port, production mode, things like this.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I'm not actively using this env variable and I'm not sure where it's coming from.